# Binding to Service in onCreate() or in onResume()

Tags: android

I want to know what is the best place in an Activity to bind to a service?
I saw examples doing it in `onResume()` and also in `onCreate()`. I was asking myself if it is not a problem putting it into `onCreate()`, because in `onPause()` I will do a unbind to the service, so I don't get a serviceConnectionLeak, if I leave the activity. Now if I press the Home Button and then switch to the Home Screen, the Activity will unbind from the service, when I go back to the Activity from the Task Manager, then `onCreate()` will not be called and if the code is trying to access a function from the service I will get a NullPointerException. If I bind and unbind only in `onResume()` and `onPause()` I don't have this problem. Am i right?

Comment: I was looking again on some examples that are binding in onCreate() they are unbinding in onDestroy() and not in onPause(). But still its not clear for me.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would generally recommend doing this in either `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` or `onStart()`/`onStop()`, depending on the semantics that you want:

- If your `Activity` wants to be interacting with the `Service` the entire time it is running (for example maybe it can retrieve some data from a network for you and will return the data when ready and you want to allow this to happen while in the background so if the user returns you will have the data ready), then `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` is probably appropriate.  Note that the semantics here is that the entire time your `Activity` is running it needs the `Service`, so if this `Service` is running in another process then you have increased the weight of it and made it more likely for it to be killed while in the background.
- If your `Activity` is only interested in working with the  `Service` while visible, then `onStart()`/`onStop()` is appropriate.  This means your `Activity` will unbind from the `Service` when the user leaves it (and it is no longer visible) and connect back up the next time the return and it is re-started and resumed.

I generally wouldn't recommend doing bind/unbind in `onResume()` and `onPause()`.  These generally won't decrease significantly the amount you use the `Service` (and thus your overhead), and in fact, because a pause and resume happens at every activity transition, this is a code path you want to keep as lightweight as possible.  Doing it here can have other unexpected negative consequences: for example if multiple `Activity`s in your app bind to the same `Service`, when there is a transition between two of those activities the `Service` may also get destroyed and recreated as the current `Activity` is paused before the next one is resumed.

Also these pairs (`onCreate()`/`onDestroy()`, `onStart()`/`onStop()`, `onPause()`/`onResume()`) are intended to be the proper pairs for acquiring and then releasing resources (such as binding to `Service`s, registering receivers, etc) to ensure that they are correctly acquired prior to being needed and released (and not leaked) when no longer needed.

Comment: Will not putting this in onResume() suffice? `if (listAdapter == null) {listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getApplicationContext());}`

Comment: but sometimes @hackbod, ... i also uncountered the same error while releasing stopService() and also unbindService() throuh onStop() method of each activities that binded to that service. and... so, to remove the error, i just put try-and-catch there and... solved! :D

Answer (score 0):

What you say is correct.  In most cases you will want to register in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`.  If you use `onCreate()` and on `onDestroy()` you will still be registering for updates when you are paused, which is being a bad citizen.  If you register in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onPause()`, when you resume the task the registration will be gone, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: "If you use OnCreate() and on Destroy() you will still be registering for updates when you are paused, which is being a bad citizen." Do you have a source you can cite for this statement?

Comment: That was my understanding but I defer to you.  Is this not correct?

Comment: Well, not as a general statement, that I am aware of. There is notion of "registering for updates" vis a vis services as a requirement. Certain services you may specifically want to unbind (and therefore perhaps shut down) when your activity goes off-screen. Others you might not. For example, a service that ties into GPS might want to shut down, but only if the application is off-screen for an extended period, so the user gets less frustrated that it has to re-acquire the GPS fix. Now, there may be other better advice than mine, which is why I was asking if you had a source.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  The point I was trying to make is that, whenever possible, I think it's a good rule to clean up as soon as you can to leave more resources for other applications.  If you have a legitimate need to hold onto the resource longer (as in your example where re-aquiring the resource is lengthy) it's less cut-and-dry.