# Stop a service when none of the activities are in the foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a service that is used by all my activities and should be stopped when none of the activities are in the foreground but keep running all the time when one activity is visible. Since Android doesn't keep an internal state to know which is the app in the foreground, is there any clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess @biquillo misunderstood your question, but I found good idea in [CommonsWare answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440811/304270)..

Basically you can start service just by Binding to it and seting flag to create it if it is not created already. Then whenever some activity is created it binds to service, onDestroy it unbinds.. That will make service be destroyed once when no activity is binded to it..

Hope it helps and it solved ur problem ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

See the lifecycle of Activity given at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Understand when the methods onStart, onStop and onPause gets invoked. You can then startService/stopService from within them accordingly.

Comment: I already know how they work, I just want to know when none of my activities are in the foreground and then be able to do something according to it.

Comment: So, you do know that onPause() gets called when some other activity comes in front of your activity and onStop() gets called when your activity is no longer visible, right?

Comment: sure, the problem is how my app knows that none of my activities are in the foreground