# never stop the service in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a service at system Level for Android which can not be stopped by a user.

Is this possible ?

How can I achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

I hope it is helpful for you.

[how to stop an android service only when there are no other activities in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440548/how-to-stop-an-android-service-only-when-there-are-no-other-activities-in-my-app)

Comment: I think you can also achieve this using following way. Override **onDestroy()** of service and add code to start your service. And you should also start your service when device rebooted.

Comment: You should never, and I really do mean *never*,  do anything in `onDestroy` that may allocate memory since you may be getting killed due to a low memory state. By allocating memory, you may be making the difference between Android correctly managing your device and you requiring a reboot because you thought you knew better than Android. This will not lead to the user experience you are aiming for.

Comment: @rivierakid Thanks for your replay. I have not knowledge about this things.