# Unbinding a service when Android goes to Lock mode

Tags: android, service, background, bind, foreground

As @hackbod stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304086/binding-to-service-in-oncreate-or-in-onresume/2304794#2304794), I used the onStart/onStop couple to bind/unbind to my service. 
I want my service to stop running when in lock mode (to save battery) and to resume when coming back. However, Lock mode works with the onResume/onPause couple. So how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for broadcast when the screen turns [on](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON)/[off](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF).

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // bind to service
  }
}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // unbind from service
  }
}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
```