# How to stop/pause an Android Service when all activities are hidden

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm working on designing an Android app, and I'm looking for information on how to implement what I thought would be a common pattern, but I can't seem to find any information about it online.

I'm going to have an application with multiple activities, and all of these activities are going to be communicating with a WiFi device over a network. So my first thought is that, since all Activities will need access to this central 'network communicator', I should create a Service to hold all of the network communication code. Great!

But now, I want to be able to save battery life, and in general make the application less obtrusive. If none of the activities from my app are visible, then I don't need to be running the network code, and I can shut down my sockets and wait. Then, when one of the activities becomes visible again, I can reconnect at that point.

Here's the problem - I don't know how to do this! Is there an existing method or pattern used to determine when all activities from my app are hidden? I don't want to disconnect/reconnect every time one of my Activities resumes or is created, because most of the time that will be from the user navigating around the app, switching between activities. I want the network connection open this whole time.

I could put some sort of 'reference counting' mechanism in my Service to keep track of when Activities appear and disappear, but that seems like overkill. I'm surprised there isn't an existing mechanism for this.

Sorry if I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using:

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
                  ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
                  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                   StopPlayer();
                    Toast.makeText(xYourClassNamex.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP. SERVICE STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
      }
```

Put the above code in on Pause() of every Class. It will toast when your app will go on `recent application` by clicking on `home` or `back` button. Now you can set any preference instead of this Toast & stop the services. Now check your preference on Resume() of every Class. If preference has any value then u can start your service.

Comment: Most users will wonder why your application needs the permission  `android.permission.GET_TASKS`. This is considered a relatively high-risk permission and will make your users think your app is some kind of spyware. The Android documentation also indicates that this method is intended to be used for debugging and not as part of core application logic.

Comment: This is not a very efficient solution, i.e. - to process a chunk of code over an iteration of tasks returned from a different service every time your activity is switched? I guess this is ok if you only have a couple activities, but even medium sized apps should not be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is to bind the Service to a base class Activity, and then to inherit your multiple classes from that one bound Activity.

Answer (score 0):

A `Bound Service` sounds like exactly what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Since you have multiple activities using this same service, you can `Bind` each one to the service, and `Unbind` the activity when it no longer needs to use the service. A great place to do this would be in your `onStart()` and `onStop()` `Activity` lifecycle methods.  The great thing about this is that when the `Service` detects that there is no `Activity` bound to it, it will kill itself.

Further reading: Great explanation by user [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236398/hackbod) on why `onStart()/onStop()` is a good option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304794/1839500