# Android: Start Activity A if service running else start activity B

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having trouble with this and can't get this to work. This is the code for empty main category launcher activity that has to show splash screen if service not running or user not authenticated else start conversations activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class EntryPoint extends Activity {
    private IAppManager imService;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            imService = ((IMService.IMBinder) service).getService();

            // this is not starting activity :(

            // Start converstion activity if service running and user ok
            if (imService.isUserAuthenticated() == true) {
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(EntryPoint.this, Conversations.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        // this is not working

        // start login activity if service disconnected

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

            imService = null;

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Splash.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Start and bind the imService
        startService(new Intent(EntryPoint.this, IMService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        try {
            unbindService(mConnection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        try {

            bindService(new Intent(EntryPoint.this, IMService.class),
                    mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run app, neither `Conversations` is run nor `Splash` activity is run but instead I see empty activity :( There is no error also, just empty `EntryPoint` activiy is run which should actually launch one of other activities.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your service is not connected and thus not able to interact with your activity.

Create an intent separately and then assign it at startService & bindService, instead of creating a new instance of intent every time for startService & bindService.

Also why are you binding the service at onResume()? Check this link out on why you should try to avoid this if possible - [Binding to Service in onCreate() or in onResume()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304086/binding-to-service-in-oncreate-or-in-onresume)

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(EntryPoint.this, IMService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried with that but it still shows blank activity although there is no error. Neither splash not conversation activity started. I dont know how to wait for service to connect and then do stuff :(