# Why Service Connection is not called in onResume?

Tags: android, service, onresume, realm

I am working on background service where i am updating one Arraylist in the service, from the Arraylist i am getting the index and playing the songs.

So what's the issue now is if i'll Intent to another activity and inside that activity i am updating the Arraylist to the service but when i am finishing the activity and coming back to MainActivity it's not updating the Arraylist again.

I am using realm arraylist for storing the data.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    songConnection();

    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    songConnection();
}

public void songConnection() {
    musicServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder) service;
            musicSrv = binder.getService();
            musicSrv.setList(musicRealmResults);
            musicBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Here the musicRealmResults is the Realm Arraylist.

In Albums.java

```
musicRealmResults = realm.where(Music.class).equalTo("albums", albums).findAllSorted("albums", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

In MainActivity.java

```
musicRealmResults = realm.where(Music.class).findAll();
```

So in both activity the Arraylist size will be different and as per the size it should update to the Service.

So please tell me why it's not updating in onResume when the activity finish.

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: You are not starting your service at all in SongConnection()

Comment: Provide some more code. Where you are starting/initializing your service?

Comment: musicSrv.setList(musicRealmResults); from where musicRealmResults comes from? Is it updating when you come back to your previous activity?

Comment: @Jois Thanks for your reply i have updated my post please go through it i am starting the service in onStart

Comment: At the beginning it will fetch all the musics from SD card store in Realm DB, i have given the name of the arraylist to musicRealmResults, in this arraylist  there four types Albums, Artist, Songs and Genre, if you are in Album activity then it will fetch album list but when i am finishing the activity it's not updating the arraylist.

Comment: hey animation check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

**change your code like this:**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    songConnection();// call this method before calling super

super.onResume();
}

public void songConnection() {
    musicServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder) service;
            musicSrv = binder.getService();
            musicSrv.setList(musicRealmResults);
            musicBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicBound = false;
        }
    };
 if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
    }

}
```

now your your service when will called correctly **But make sure you stop the Service at some point of time before it'
s started again.** ThankYou I hope this was helpful.

Comment: hey thanks but still the same it's not updating the musicRealmResults still the older size it's taking, it should update the size to the service.

Comment: did you change you onResume method also?? i have changed it check it out

Comment: yes i have updated the onResume before super.onResume only i am calling that method

Comment: i did read some blog now. i am sorry but it's not appropriate to startservice in onRESUME() SO I THINk it's better you put the whole code in onStart()

Comment: but try what i changed now! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304086/binding-to-service-in-oncreate-or-in-onresume

Comment: and check this out